# uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < angular.min.js:1

Tags: angularjs, uncaught-exception

What could be the possible reason behind the same? I am unable to resolve the issue. APIs are working well and just because of this error I am unable to integrate it with frontend.

here`s index.js file:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="todoApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>::CRUD::</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="core.js"></script> 
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
<body ng-controller="mainController">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <h1>Todo CRUD App<span class="label label-info">{{ todos.length }}</span></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="todo-list" class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="todo in todos">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-click="deleteTodo(todo._id)">{{todo.text}}
          </label>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="todo-form" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-center">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg text-center" placeholder="Add a todo here" ng-model="formData.text">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="createTodo()">Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>  
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please post some code?

Comment: As it is the first char in angular.min.js it is most likely, because you do not receive the angular JS file, but an error Html page. See you browser console. I am very sure, that the status code of your request to angular.min.js is != 200.

Comment: @scipper But the path of file and CDN is correct. I have cross checked many times. On click it leads to the correct URL/Path

Comment: @KaustubhKhare please find the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys, Error is resolved. I just had to add `type="javascript"` in script tags.

Comment: `type="javascript"` is already implied in HTML5 so I’d be highly surprised it fixed your error. In fact, the HTML5 spec encourages authors to _omit_ that attribute if it’s redundant (which it is here).

Comment: It genuinely fixed my error. Even I was surprised. @bfontaine

Answer (score -2):

I think you haven't specified your app in your file.
Like this..

```
  <div ng-app="exampleApp">
```

You have only specified your controller.

Comment: I am getting 200 Ok as status code for angular.min.js

Comment: You only have specified your controller in your body tag, but you forget to specify your app.

Comment: I have added the same in HTML tag.

Comment: have you loaded your controller.js and app.js file

Comment: yes, core.js represents the same. Still the server is unable to find it.

Comment: Try this version of angular js

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: Why is Your HTML File name index.js ?